# Type lacks a call signature

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am not sure what I am missing, but I have a function that looks like this:

```
export default function (config: DatabaseConnections<DatabaseConnection>) {
  return DB['connect'](config, throwError)
}
```

When I try to use the function (in my js test case), I would like to use it like this:

```
const db = require('../lib/DB')
db({
  master: {
    host: 'abc123',
    user: 'abc123',
    password: 'abc123',
    database: 'abc123'
  }
})
```

However, when I do that I get the error:

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.

When I call it like this `db.default({...})` it works. How can I get it to export the function so I can call it like this `db({...})`?

Comment: You should use `import`.

Comment: I am testing in a js file so `'import ... =' can only be used in a .ts file.`

Comment: Why don't use a .ts file if you are developing with TypesScript?

Comment: @RômuloM.Farias I am writing test cases for my lib

Comment: Is it necessary to have the `default` export instead of simple export>

Comment: @Niladri If I do `export function db()` instead, I have to call `db.db()`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn have you tried using `const db = require('../lib/DB').default;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to fix this

**Simple fix**

You can try grabbing the default off the require:

```
const db = require('../lib/DB').default;
```

**Named Function Fixes**

You could also try naming the function rather than relying on the default.

In your DB file, try:

```
export default function db (...)
```

and then in your test file:

```
const db = require('../lib/DB').db;
```

You can also name and export only the specific function, rather than using a default.

A la:

```
function db(...){ }
module.exports=db;
```

And then in your test file:

```
const db = require('../lib/DB');
```

**Bonus Return Type Fix**

Since the db function returns a value, you need to define a return type on the function.

```
export default function (config: DatabaseConnections<DatabaseConnection>):DB {
  return DB['connect'](config, throwError);
}
```

Comment: `DB['connect']` returns the class `DB`, however, it still gives the same error

Comment: Gotcha. So, for the require syntax, I think you can grab the method off the require call, and assign that into db.

Comment: figured it out: if I do `function db(){/* do stuff */}; module.exports=db` then this works

Comment: Also `const db = require('../lib/DB').default;` should work same

Comment: Cool cool. The manual module.export works because you have now named the function. I'll update w/alternate syntax.

Comment: Is there a built in way for **TypeScript** to do this or do I have to go with the straight JavaScript/Node approach?

Comment: Depends on what you're working with. At my work we don't use require. We just use module imports:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

This allows us to say import {methodName} from 'modulePath';

I think imports are standard, but it depends on what browser you're targeting.

Comment: I am targeting `Node`, which currently doesn't support import.

Comment: See section:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter#what-if-a-library-isnt-on-definitelytyped